# take input from user using socket.io notification

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, socket.io, callback

I'm trying to create a notification system using socket.io in nodejs, but i also want the client to give an input within the notification

I tried by adding a callback function within the emit function but it's not working.
Is there any better approach to achieve  this?

```js
io.to(socketId).emit('notification', message, (Confirm: Boolean) => {
  if (Confirm) {
    // do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.io - socket.on wait for promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608923/socket-io-socket-on-wait-for-promise)

Comment: If you look at the second code block of the linked answer, it appears to directly answer your question with a neat example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609250/13378247

Comment: sorry I didn't fully get it, my problem is that I don't want to send callback immediately, once the user gives input then only callback should execute, is it possible?